# I want to scrape all the events information but after I put for loop it is not working. Is there any advice to fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://10times.com/melaka-my').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for events in soup.find_all('div', class_= 'col-md-8 col-sm-12 pull-right'):

    title = events.find('table', class_='listing text-muted').h2.a.text
    print(title)

    # to find date
    eventdate = events.find('tr', class_='box').td.text
    print (eventdate)

    #to find place
    place = events.find('span', class_='venue text-drkr').text
    print(place)

    print()
```

Comment: See answer below, but for future reference - this isn't the right way to ask questions on SO. Start with https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use pandas' `.read_html()`?

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('https://10times.com/melaka-my')
df = dfs[0].dropna(0)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
                                 Date                                         Event Name                                              Venue                                        Description                                               Type                    Unnamed: 5
0   Mon, 01 - Fri, 05 Jul 2019ongoing  International Conference on Youth, Ocean and S...                                AMES Hotel, Malacca                               Be an Ocean Champion  Conference Education & Training Environment & ...        Interested 2 following
1          Tue, 06 - Thu, 08 Aug 2019  Melaka International Intellectual Exposition (...  Universiti Teknologi MARA, Cawangan Melaka, Ka...  The Melaka International Intellectual Expositi...  Conference Business Services Education & Training        Interested 8 following
2          Wed, 07 - Sat, 10 Aug 2019  Theory & Technique International Aerosol Confe...                       Hatten Hotel Melaka, Malacca  Theory & Technique International Aerosol Confe...  Conference Education & Training Environment & ...                    Interested
4          Fri, 16 - Sun, 18 Aug 2019                                         Matta Fair           MITC CONVENTION CENTRE, Malacca, Malacca  Matta Fair provides global exposure and endles...                         Tradeshow Travel & Tourism       Interested 59 following
5          Tue, 20 - Wed, 21 Aug 2019  International Conference on Medical & Health S...                      Bayview Hotel Melaka, Malacca  The International Conference on Medical & Heal...  Conference Medical & Pharma Wellness, Health &...        Interested 7 following
6          Tue, 20 - Wed, 21 Aug 2019  International Conference on Management, Econom...                      Bayview Hotel Melaka, Malacca  Leading forum for the presentation of new adva...                    Conference Education & Training                    Interested
7          Tue, 20 - Wed, 21 Aug 2019  International Conference on Science, Engineeri...                      Bayview Hotel Melaka, Malacca  Leading forum for the presentation of new adva...    Conference Education & Training IT & Technology                    Interested
8          Wed, 21 - Thu, 22 Aug 2019  International Islamic Heritage Conference (ISHEC)  Universiti Teknologi MARA, Cawangan Melaka, Ka...  The International Islamic Heritage Conference ...  Conference Business Services Education & Train...        Interested 3 following
9          Mon, 26 - Tue, 27 Aug 2019  Global Congress on Construction, Material and ...                      Hotel Novotel Melaka, Malacca    Towards sustainable structures and construction  Conference Building & Construction Education &...        Interested 3 following
10         Wed, 28 - Thu, 29 Aug 2019  International Language Culture and Education C...                        Holiday Inn Melaka, Malacca  Language, culture and education as gateways to...         Conference Education & Training Paid entry       Interested 11 following
11         Thu, 29 - Fri, 30 Aug 2019  International Conference on Mechanical & Manuf...  THE MUDZAFFAR HOTEL (Ayer keroh, Melaka) 5 Sta...  International Conference on Mechanical & Manuf...                  Conference Industrial Engineering                    Interested
12         Sat, 07 - Sun, 08 Sep 2019  International Academy of Pathology Malaysian D...         DoubleTree by Hilton Hotel Melaka, Malacca  International Academy of Pathology Malaysian D...     Conference Medical & Pharma Science & Research                    Interested
13         Mon, 21 - Tue, 22 Oct 2019  International Conference Business, Tourism and...      Kings Green Hotel City Centre Melaka, Malacca  The International Conference Business, Tourism...      Conference Travel & Tourism Business Services        Interested 1 following
15         Fri, 25 - Sun, 27 Oct 2019                   Taste Fully Food & Beverage Expo  Melaka International Trade Centre (MITC), Malacca  Taste Fully Food & Beverage Expo will deliver ...                         Tradeshow Food & Beverages  Interested 110 following 4.0
16     Wed, 30 Oct - Fri, 01 Nov 2019                 Hospitality and Tourism Conference  Universiti Teknologi MARA, Cawangan Melaka, Ka...  Hospitality and Tourism Conference will focus ...  Conference Travel & Tourism Hotel, Restaurant ...        Interested 3 following
17         Mon, 18 - Tue, 19 Nov 2019  International Conference on Social Sciences Re...                   Hotel Equatorial Melaka, Malacca  International Conference on Social Sciences Re...                      Conference Science & Research                    Interested
18         Mon, 16 - Tue, 17 Dec 2019               international Scientific Forum (ISF)  THE MUDZAFFAR HOTEL (Ayer keroh, Melaka) 5 Sta...  international Scientific Forum gives the parti...   Conference Electric & Electronics Power & Energy                    Interested
19                   Mon, 23 Dec 2019  International Conference on Communication, Inf...                                            Malacca  The I-CITYS will provide the ideal opportunity...        Conference Travel & Tourism IT & Technology        Interested 3 following
20         Wed, 22 - Thu, 23 Jan 2020  International Conference on Soft Computing and...                        Holiday Inn Melaka, Malacca                    Soft Computing for Data Science                         Conference IT & Technology        Interested 1 following
21         Fri, 20 - Sat, 21 Mar 2020  International Conference On Law & Political Sc...                      Bayview Hotel Melaka, Malacca  Provides a leading forum for the presentation ...                    Conference Education & Training       Interested 16 following
22         Tue, 07 - Thu, 09 Apr 2020  Asia's International Feed, Livestock & Meat In...           MITC CONVENTION CENTRE, Malacca, Malacca  The Asia's International Feed, Livestock & Mea...          Tradeshow Food & Beverages Animals & Pets       Interested 12 following
23         Fri, 17 - Sun, 19 Apr 2020  Advances in Economics and Business Issues Rese...                   Hotel Equatorial Melaka, Malacca  Advances in Economics and Business Issues Rese...                    Conference Education & Training        Interested 9 following
24         Fri, 17 - Sun, 19 Apr 2020  Current Research In Information Technology, Ma...                   Hotel Equatorial Melaka, Malacca  The Current Research In Information Technology...  Conference Scientific Instruments Education & ...        Interested 3 following
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to modify your code as follows:

```
events = soup.find_all('td',class_="text-drkr")

for event in events:
    print(event.text)
    print(event.findNext('h2').text)
    print(event.findNext('span', class_="venue text-drkr").text)
    print('-----------')
```

Output:

```
Mon, 01  - Fri, 05 Jul 2019ongoing
International Conference on Youth, Ocean and South Development Goals
AMES Hotel, Malacca
-----------
Tue, 06  - Thu, 08 Aug 2019
Melaka International Intellectual Exposition (MIIEx)
Universiti Teknologi MARA, Cawangan Melaka, Kampus Bandaraya Melaka., Malacca
-----------
```

etc.